# Socket error while connecting to IDE on 127.0.0.1:10000

Tags: maui

I am testing out .NET Maui, and I just created a new project and built and ran it. I am using Rider, and in the Run window I see this message, it doesn't look detrimental but I am still concerned. I haven't found much on it on the web. Is there anything that I need to do?

`MauiApp1[45430:325228] Microsoft.iOS: Socket error while connecting to IDE on 127.0.0.1:10000: Connection refused`

[image]

Comment: We are having the same error while the iOS simulator opens our Maui application: Microsoft.iOS: Socket error while connecting to IDE on 127.0.0.1:10000: Connection refused. Any news on a fix?

Comment: I have reported to Jetbrains for help. You can track it here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-104973/Rider-2023.3.3-Maui-3-warnings